# Consider Bitcoin Price goes down to $3000, what will be the effect on miners (will they stop mining) and the affect on difficulty to mine a Bitcoin?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-theory, mining-hardware, mining-profitability

Over a set period of time (around 10 mins for BTC), a number of transactions are compiled into a block by a miner, and then the block is verified on the general ledger and added to the list of blocks which make up the blockchain.

Consider the price of Bitcoin goes down to $3000, will this effect Mining operation go on?

What actually going to happen to the difficulty of solving problems in mining?

Thank you in advance.

---

Regards,

Raghu Ariga

Answer (score 1):

More than a question ***it seems like you are asking for a prediction of behavior***. What miners will do eventually, and how `getdifficulty` will be affected, has been central to many conversations around Bitcoin.

In my honest opinion, **even at 3000 USD per BTC it is still highly profitable** for miners. The key factor is if miners need to move their generated Bitcoins to fiat money to pay bills.

If a miner or mining pool manages to avoid these payments based on future price -something they should aim at-, they will be doing quite good with even 1000 USD per Bitcoin.

Remember that *we are creating the Bitcoin/Frame/Economy*. Trading for fiat currency is just not the main idea behind cryptocurrencies.

Comment: There was a survey recently about cost of mining bitcoins that's relevant to this discussion: http://www.ibtimes.com/bitcoin-mining-cost-lowest-venezuela-highest-south-korea-report-finds-2646191